# Get column value from a different table using select

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this query on my interactor:

```
 Variant.where(code: context.codes)
        .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN prices p
                ON p.variant_id = variants.id")
        .select("code,
                 actual_price,
                 selling_price,
                 p.cost")
```

which returns:

```
#<Interactor::Context codes=["PRDCTA-V1", "PRDCTA-V2"], body=[#<Variant id: nil, selling_price: nil, code: "PRDCTA-V2", actual_price: nil>,
#<Variant id: nil, selling_price: #<BigDecimal:7ff1d13b9118,'0.1E3',9(18)>, code: "PRDCTA-V1", actual_price: nil>]
```

I don't know why the `p.cost` from the `prices` table does not appear which means my select is wrong. I have tried to change it to `cost`, `prices.cost` still does not work.

my expected output should be

```
[#<Variant id: nil, selling_price: nil, code: "PRDCTA-V2", actual_price: nil, cost:{value here}>,
```

Comment: It doesn't appear, but is anyway accessible, try `<your_query>.first.cost`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma edit: it did appear! but why? Is there a way I can include it with my result?

Comment: Is in memory, but isn't "pushed" to the variant objects. You can just iterate and invoke that column name as a method. Or do you need a special way to represent them?

Comment: You can use `.map(&:attributes)` to turn the list of records into plain hashes, these _will_ have the key `cost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in select assign an alias to cost

```
p.cost AS price_cost
```

Then, fetch it by `variants.first.price_cost`

OR, just fetch it from `attributes`

```
variants.first.attributes['cost']
```

will return the cost.

Hope that helps!